# Building libopenmetaverse on CentOS 5

Tags: mono, build, nant, centos

I'm trying to build [libopenmetaverse](http://lib.openmetaverse.org/) on CentOS however I get the following error. I'm not this kind of developer and am installing this for someone else to use. This is just the part of the build that fails. Any ideas?

```
     [nant] /opt/libomv/Programs/WinGridProxy/WinGridProxy.exe.build build
            Buildfile: file:///opt/libomv/Programs/WinGridProxy/WinGridProxy.exe.build
            Target framework: Mono 2.0 Profile
            Target(s) specified: build


            build:

                 [echo] Build Directory is /opt/libomv/bin
                  [csc] Compiling 15 files to '/opt/libomv/bin/WinGridProxy.exe'.
                           [resgen] Error: Invalid ResX input.
                           [resgen] Position: Line 2700, Column 5.
                           [resgen] Inner exception: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus

            BUILD FAILED

            External Program Failed: /tmp/tmp5a71a509.tmp/resgen.exe (return code was 1)

            Total time: 0.4 seconds.


BUILD FAILED

Nested build failed.  Refer to build log for exact reason.

Total time: 47 seconds.

Build Exit Code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, dont know why, but installing libgdiplus-devel seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to install libgdiplus, or ensure that your system can find it.